# Are there any sensors out there that detect how tightly a particular object is held by a human hand?

Tags: sensor, android

I'm trying to find a solution for quantitatively measuring the amount of tightness with which a smartphone is held by a human hand.

Is there any way of using the current sensors in an Android phone to achieve the said requirements? If not, is there any external sensor available that can be used with a microcontroller like Arduino to do a similar thing?

Comment: You will have to make your own sensor package and interface. One sensor technology is a strain gauge.

Comment: Modifying a rubber case with some strain gauges and using Arduino could work well.

Comment: Hmmm... How about getting a baseline by turning on the mic, running the vibrator, and recording the mic and/or accelerometer.  Compare free air conditions to different grip forces and materials of the recorded data.  Plot up the results, and share the profits with me.